# Mathematical solution for bezier curve and line intersection in coffeescript (or any language I understand)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bezier

I found a [forum question](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=64459) with...

```
Function intersectBezier3Line(x1#,y1#,vx1#,vy1#,x2#,y2#,vx2#,vy2#,L1x#,L1y#,L2x#,L2y#)

        Local A#,B#,C#,E#,F#,G#,La#,Lb#,Lc#,Solution#

                A=3*vx1+x2-(3*vx2)-x1
        B=3*x1-(6*vx1)+(3*vx2)
        C=3*vx1-(3*x1)

                E=3*vy1+y2-(3*vy2)-y1
        F=3*y1-(6*vy1)+(3*vy2)
        G=3*vy1-(3*y1)

        La=L2y-L1y
        Lb=L1x-L2x
        Lc=L1y*(L2x-L1x) + L1x*(L1y-L2y)



                ax(4)=La*x1 + Lb*y1 + Lc
        ax(3)=La*C  + Lb*G
        ax(2)=La*B  + Lb*F
        ax(1)=La*A  + Lb*E

       FindRootsPoly3(ax(4),ax(3),ax(2),ax(1)) 

End Function

Function  FindRootsPoly3(A3#,A2#,A1#,A0#)

    Local fc2#,gc2#,hc2#,Rc2#,Sc2#,Tc2#,Uc2#,ic2#,jc2#,kc2#,Lc2#,Mc2#,Nc2#,Pc2#

    fc2 =( (3*A1/A3) - ((A2^2)/(A3^2) ))/ 3
    gc2=(( (2*A2^3)/(A3^3)) - (9*A2*A1/(A3^2)) + (27*A0/A3)) / 27
    hc2 = ((gc2^2)/4) + ((fc2^3)/27)

    If hc2>0 Then
                Rc2 = -(gc2/2) + (Sqr(hc2))
                If Rc2<0 Then 
                    Sc2 = -(Abs(Rc2)^0.333333)
                Else
                    Sc2 = ((Rc2))^0.333333
                EndIf
                Tc2 = -(gc2/2) -( Sqr(hc2))
                If Tc2<0 Then 
                    Uc2 = -(Abs(Tc2)^0.333333)
                Else
                    Uc2 = (Tc2)^0.333333
                EndIf
                Rx(0) = (Sc2 + Uc2) - (A2/(3*A3))
                Else
                If hc2=0 And gc2=0 And fc2=0 Then
                    Rx(0) =-((A0/A3)^0.3333333 )
                Else
                    If hc2<0 Or hc2=0 Then
                        ic2= Sqr(((gc2^2)/4) - hc2)
                        jc2 = (ic2)^0.333333
                        kc2 = ACos (- (gc2 / (2*ic2)))
                        Lc2 = -jc2
                        Mc2 = Cos (kc2/3)
                        Nc2 = Sqr( 3) * Sin (kc2/3)
                        Pc2 = -(A2/(3*A3))
                        Rx(0) = 2*jc2 * Cos(kc2/3) -(A2/(3*A3))
                        Rx(1) = Lc2 * (Mc2 + Nc2) + Pc2
                        Rx(2) = Lc2 * (Mc2 - Nc2) + Pc2
                   EndIf        
              EndIf
    EndIf
End Function
```

Which I expect to somehow output points of intersection between a line and a bezier curve. I translated into coffeescript

```
intersectBezier3Line = (x1,y1,vx1,vy1,x2,y2,vx2,vy2,L1x,L1y,L2x,L2y)->

  A=3*vx1+x2-(3*vx2)-x1
  B=3*x1-(6*vx1)+(3*vx2)
  C=3*vx1-(3*x1)

  E=3*vy1+y2-(3*vy2)-y1
  F=3*y1-(6*vy1)+(3*vy2)
  G=3*vy1-(3*y1)

  La=L2y-L1y
  Lb=L1x-L2x
  Lc=L1y*(L2x-L1x) + L1x*(L1y-L2y)

  ax = [
    La*x1 + Lb*y1 + Lc
    La*C  + Lb*G
    La*B  + Lb*F
    La*A  + Lb*E
  ]

  FindRootsPoly3 ax[3],ax[2],ax[1],ax[0]

pow = (x,y)-> Math.pow x,y
sqr = (x)-> x*x 

FindRootsPoly3 = (A3,A2,A1,A0)->

  fc2 = ((3*A1 / A3) - ( pow(A2,2) / pow(A3,2) ))/ 3
  gc2 = (( (2*pow(A2,3)) / pow(A3,3)) - (9*A2*A1 / pow(A3,2)) + (27*A0 / A3)) / 27
  hc2 = (pow(gc2,2)/4) + (pow(fc2,3)/27)

  Rx = []
  if hc2>0
    Rc2 = -(gc2/2) + (sqr(hc2))
    if Rc2<0
      Sc2 = -(pow(Math.abs(Rc2),0.333333))
    else
      Sc2 = pow(((Rc2)),0.333333)

    Tc2 = -(gc2/2) - ( sqr(hc2))
    if Tc2<0
      Uc2 = -pow(Math.abs(Tc2),0.333333)
    else
      Uc2 = pow((Tc2),0.333333)

    Rx[0] = (Sc2 + Uc2) - (A2/(3*A3))
  else
    if hc2==0 and gc2==0 and fc2==0
      Rx[0] = -pow((A0/A3),0.3333333 )
    else
      if hc2<0 or hc2==0
        ic2 = sqr((pow(gc2,2)/4) - hc2)
        jc2 = pow((ic2),0.333333)
        kc2 = Math.acos( -(gc2 / (2*ic2)))
        Lc2 = -jc2
        Mc2 = Math.cos(kc2/3)
        Nc2 = sqr( 3) * Math.sin(kc2/3)
        Pc2 = -(A2/(3*A3))
        Rx[0] = 2*jc2 * Math.cos(kc2 / 3) - (A2/(3*A3))
        Rx[1] = Lc2 * (Mc2 + Nc2) + Pc2
        Rx[2] = Lc2 * (Mc2 - Nc2) + Pc2
  Rx
```

And sometimes (with some inputs) it outputs something, but mostly just `NaN` and `undefined`. I don't know what exactly it should be outputting, is it the value of `t` on the initial bezier curve?

Also, it is clearly not working correctly. Can anyone see anyhting wrong with my translation, or the initial code?

I would really like to be able to mathematically intersect a bezier curve with a line in javascript/coffeescript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest mistake is that in vbscript `Sqr` is not "square", it's "square root"

Edit: (nevermind previous comments that were here)

Edit II:  not a problem with your translation, but it seems the original code had a few bugs in defining the polynomial to solve:

```
bezier4poly = (A,B,C,D) ->
    [
        -A + 3*B + -3*C + D 
        3*A - 6*B + 3*C
        -3*A + 3*B
        A 
    ]
intersectBezier3Line2 = (Px0,Py0,Px1,Py1,Px2,Py2,Px3,Py3,Lx0,Ly0,Lx1,Ly1)->

    ### (x_2 - x_1)(y - y_1)=(y_2 - y_1)(x - x_1) =>  ### 
    ###(y_1 - y_2)x + (x_2 - x_1)y   + (x_1(y_2 - y_1) + - y_1(x_2 - x_1)) =>  Ax + By + C = 0  ###
    A=Ly0-Ly1
    B=Lx1-Lx0
    C=Lx0*(Ly1-Ly0) + -Ly0*(Lx1-Lx0)

    ax = bezier4poly(Px0,Px1,Px2,Px3)
    ay = bezier4poly(Py0,Py1,Py2,Py3)
    p = [
        A*ax[0] + B*ay[0]
        A*ax[1] + B*ay[1]
        A*ax[2] + B*ay[2]
        A*ax[3] + B*ay[3]  + C
    ]

    findRootsPoly3 p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]
```

using this, taking the result of this and sorting

```
intersectBezier3Line2(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)
```

gives

```
[-6.212270483585414e-7, 0.49999999999999994, 1.0000006212270485]
```

which is close to what I'd intuit as values of t for which the bezier curve of t is next to the line defined by (0,0), (1,1) , but I'm not close to calling this bug free, it just "seems to work".

Comment: That is spot on. The Sqr is the problem. I changed my sqr function to return the root, and as if bmaic, it all worked. There are still some edge cases that it does not work for, for example, the start of the bezier curve falling on the line it is to intersect with, and also calculating crossing point where the tangents are equal at the point of crossing. There are probably more, but this is a great start. Thanks a lot. I have not tried your code yet, it might solve some of these issues. I will give it a go, you look like you know what you are talking about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Obj-C I posted a question about creating bezier curves. With the answer to correct things its a working function.

[Bezier curve algorithm in objective-c needs a tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466302/bezier-curve-algorithm-in-objective-c-needs-a-tweak)