# iOS adding points to quadratic curves and manipulating

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm starting out with a straight line, as shown below.
[image]

I need the user to be able to drag and manipulate this line with their finger in real time.  So they might end up with a series or curves as below:

[image]

It is simple to do this with one curve, as in the code below.

```
    - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    controlPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect controlRect = CGRectMake(controlPoint.x - 50.0, controlPoint.y - 50.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:controlRect];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0 , screenHeight/2 + gapDistance);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, controlPoint.x + gapDistance, controlPoint.y + gapDistance, 100, screenHeight/2 + gapDistance);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

My question is, how do I do it with multiple curves?  I will also need to be able to add smaller curves to existing curves if the user so desires.

Comment: I think what you're looking for are Bézier curves. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466302/bezier-curve-algorithm-in-objective-c-needs-a-tweak

Comment: Definitely, but I'm not sure how to go from one curve to multiple in real time in response to user input